# Change a View from inside a Timer Function

Tags: java, android, timer

I need to have my TextView be blue for half a second, and then turn white again (user clicks, it blinks blue).

To do this, I tried setting the colour to blue, setting a 500ms timer, and then changing it back to white. Like this:

```
// defining the TextView
final TextView showDatabase = new TextView(this);
showDatabase.setText("Show Database");
showDatabase.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);

// click listener
showDatabase.setOnClickListener (new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {

        showDatabase.setTextColor(Color.BLUE); // make it blue

        // wait 500ms, then make it white again
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
               showDatabase.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            }
        }, 500);
    }
});
```

Logcat:

```
Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
```

I can't simply create an instance of the TextView inside the timer function (I think) because it's not an element on a layout.

**How can I let myself manipulate the TextView from inside the timer function?**

Comment: runonuithread android

Comment: Take a look at runOnUiThread()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Timer runs on a different thread. You cannot update ui from there. Use a `Handler` or `runOnUiThread`.

```
  runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                         showDatabase.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                    }
                });
```

Using `Handler`

```
Handler m_handler;
Runnable m_handlerTask ; 
m_handler = new Handler(); 
m_handlerTask = new Runnable() 
{ 
@Override
public void run() {
  showDatabase.setTextColor(Color.WHITE); 
  m_handler.postDelayed(m_handlerTask, 500); 
 }
 };
 m_handlerTask.run();
```

To cancel

```
m_handler.removeCallbacks(m_handlerTask);
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm using the `runOnUiThread` and it works. However, your `Handler` code doesn't compile for me because there are non-final variables. If I make them final, they need to be initialized.

Comment: @mikeyaworski declare them as instance variables. Handler will work. Handler is associated with the thread in which it is created. You don;t need a thread to update ui as timer is not the best choice. If you are doing heavy operations then a thread is required

Answer (score 2):

Add a `runOnUiThread` in your timer:

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
     @Override
     public void run() {
         runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
             @Override
             public void run() {
                 // do UI updates here
             }
         });
     }
}, 500);
```